# How to get stage coordinates on drop event kineticjs

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've a 'p' elements with a text. This elements should be drop on the stage with the mouse position when the 'drop event' been shoot.
My code is:

Html code:

```
<ul>
  <li><p id= "1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Element1</p></li>
  <li><p id= "2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Element2</p></li>
  <li><p id= "3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Element3</p></li>
  <li><p id= "4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Element4</p></li>
  <li><p id= "5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Element5</p></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    var stage,modsLayer;

    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
              container: 'container',
              width: $('#container').width(),
              height: 600
    );
    stage.on('drop',function(e){
        //get stage mouse position coordinates to insert a text
    });
    modsLayer = new Kinetic.Layer(); 
    stage.add(modsLayer);

    $('.kineticjs-content canvas').attr('id','canvas');
    $('.kineticjs-content canvas').attr('ondrop','drop(event)');
    $('.kineticjs-content canvas').attr('ondragover','allowDrop(event)');

    function allowDrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    function drop(e) {  
      stage.fire('drop');  
    };

    function drag(e) { 
      switch(e.target.tagName){
        case "P":
          e.dataTransfer.setData("comp_id",e.target.id);
          e.dataTransfer.setData("comp_name",e.target.innerText);  
          e.dataTransfer.setData("tagName",e.target.tagName);
        break;
    };
```

Comment: The relative coordinates to stage not working with the drop event.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have a similar problem.  I'm dropping <img /> onto kineticjs canvas but can't find the coordinates of the top left of the image dropped in relation to the canvas.

Comment: The relative coordinates to stage not working with the drop event.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation I used the jQuery UI draggable functionality (because the HTML5 drag functionality did not seem to work across browsers) to first mark the images (my components) I wanted to be able to drag onto the Kinetic JS canvas and determine the start and stop functions:

```
$(".component").draggable
    cursor: "crosshair"
    cursorAt:
        left: 0
        top: 0
    distance: 10
    helper: "clone"
    opacity: 0.5
    start: (e, ui) ->
        layoutDragStart e, ui
    stop: (e, ui) ->
        layoutDragStop e, ui
```

(This is in coffeescript)

With the following layoutDragStart (to extract the data I wanted to transfer), layoutDragStop:

```
layoutDragStart = (e, ui) ->
    $(ui.helper).data "component", $(e.currentTarget).data("component")
    $(ui.helper).data "height", $(e.currentTarget).data("height")
    $(ui.helper).data "width", $(e.currentTarget).data("width")

layoutDragStop = (e, ui) ->
    height = $(ui.helper).data "height"
    width = $(ui.helper).data "width"
    x = (ui.position.left - $("#layoutCanvas").position().left + parseFloat(width) / 2)
    y = (ui.position.top - $("#layoutCanvas").position().top + parseFloat(height) / 2)
```

followed by code to add required elements to the canvas.